# How to adjust <li> tag inside a bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm targetting the the li with the value Tracking inside the ul and want to adjust the height to auto or 100%. None of these work. I haven't had a way of correctly targetting that li so it fits the whole navbar height.

[image: navbar]

```
<nav id="admin_navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Tracking</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS I've tried to do. Color and background are to make sure I was targetting it. I wasn't and I don't know why. I've tried a lot of different combinations

```
.nav>ul{
height: auto;
background-color: white;
color: red;
}
```

Comment: You can try add to parent element `position:relative` and child element should have `position:absoute; top:0,right:0;bottom:0;left:0;`

Comment: try to give .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0 -15px;
}`